# Wordpress categories hierachy issue

Tags: categories

I have problem with my catogories in my custom post type. I am trying to do a basic apartments booking system. I created custom post called Apartments and then I added a categories. The category tree looks like this:

Countries - Spain -- Barcelona -- Madrid - Greece -- Athenes

and so on.

I want to achive effect when the user enter to the apartment in Barcelona, the higher category will be displayed in header (in this example Spain). When the user eneter to the apartment in Athenes the Greece category should be in header. I tried solution that I have found on stack but it does not work for me.

```
    $category = get_the_category();

    foreach ($category as $cat) {
      echo $cat->name;
    }
    $ancestors = get_ancestors( $category[0]->term_id, 'category' );
    $direct_parent_id = $ancestors[0];

    echo $direct_parent_id;
```

I used above code in a post template. Only the second category is displayed and as you can see the categories are displayed in alphabetical order instead of hierarchical.

I hope you understand what I mean.

Thank you in advance for directions

Comment: You said you are using a "custom post type". But are you using a custom taxonomy also? Because `get_the_category()` only returns results from the default "category" taxonomy. For custom taxonomies use `get_the_terms()`. Maybe this is the problem. Also, with `get_the_category()` you will get the category of the _current_ post.

Comment: I don't use custom taxonomy. Now I will read information about it and try to implement it.